System of local isos gives system of local epis
Suppose that $W$ is a system of local isomorphisms on a presheaf topos $\mathbf{Pre}(\mathcal{C})$. We say a map in $W$ is a $W$-local isomorphism, and we say that a map of presheaves $f: X \to Y$ is a $W$-local epimorphism if $\text{im}(f) \hookrightarrow Y$ is a $W$-local isomorphism. Let $E$ denote the class of $W$-local epimorphisms. I would like to show that $E$ is a system of local epimorphisms (Note that condition LE4 on the nlab is different from Kashiwara-Schapira in that they ask for an iff, this is the definition I will take). This question is also stated as Exercise 16.5 of Kashiwara-Schapira - Categories and Sheaves. I was easily able to show that $E$ satisfies LE1, LE3 and LE4, but for some reason LE2 (composition of local epis is a local epi) eludes me. I'd appreciate any help on this.

Consider first the case of local epis $p : E \to F$ and $q : F \to C(-, U)$.  The images $R = \mathrm{im}(q)$ and $S = \mathrm{im}(qp)$ are sieves on $U$, and $R$ is covering because $q$ is a local epi.  For any $f : V \to U$ in $R$ there's some $y$ in $F(V)$ such that $q(y) = f$, and pulling back $p$ along $y$ gives a local epi $p'$ as in the diagram
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
 E' & \xrightarrow{p'} & C(-,V) \\
{y'}\downarrow & & \downarrow{y} \\
 E & \xrightarrow{p} & F 
\end{array}
$$
Since $p'$ is a local epi, the sieve $S' = \mathrm{im}(p')$ on $V$ is covering.  And we have an inclusion of sieves $S' \subseteq f^{*}S$:
if $g : W \to V$ belongs to $S'$, then there's some $e'$ in $E'(W)$ such that $p'(e') = g$ and so $q(p(y'(e'))) = fg$, putting $fg$ in $S$.  Since $f^{*}S$ contains a covering sieve it's also covering, and since $S$ pulls back to a covering sieve along every element of the cover $R$ it's also a cover.  Therefore $S = \mathrm{im}(qp) \hookrightarrow C(-, U)$ is a local isomorphism, making $qp$ a local epimorphism.
So if $p : E \to F$ and $q : F \to G$ are local epis, then for any $z$ in $G(U)$ we have a pullback diagram
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
 E' & \xrightarrow{p'} & F' & \xrightarrow{q'} & C(-, U) \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow{z} \\
 E & \xrightarrow{p} & F & \xrightarrow{q} & G 
\end{array}
$$
Since pullback preserves local epis, both $p'$ and $q'$ are local epis, and by the special case above it follows that $q'p'$ is a local epi.  By LE4 it follows that $qp$ is a local epi.

Excellent, thank you so much!

For others who might get stuck here: First one needs to prove two lemmas. (1) If $W$ is a system of local isomorphisms, and $R \subseteq y(U)$ is in $W$, $S \subseteq y(U)$ is a sieve and $R \subseteq S$, then $S \subseteq y(U)$ is in $W$. To prove this all you do is show that the square with $R = R$ on the top and $R \subseteq S$, $S \subseteq y(U)$ and $R \subseteq y(U)$ on the other sides is a pullback, since the pullback is $R \cap S = R$.

(2) If $W$ is a system of local isos, and $R \subseteq y(U)$ is in $W$, $S \subseteq y(U)$ and for all $f \in R$, $f^(R) \subseteq y(U)$ is in $W$, then $S \subseteq y(U)$ is in $W$. To prove this, you show that $R \cap S \subseteq R$ is in $W$, by pulling back by arbitrary $g: y(V) \to R$. This gives you $g^(S)$, and by assumption this was in $W$.
